# How to align the checkbox and text in cell to center in ag grid angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-ng2

I have an angular application in that I need to align the checkbox and text to center in table cells.

**.component.ts**

```
 columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
  { headerName:'Select',width: 80,field:'select',checkboxSelection:true },
    { headerName:'Action Code',field: 'ActionCode' ,width: 120},
    { headerName:'Action Name',field: 'ActionName' ,width: 180},
    { headerName:'Due Date',field: 'DueDate',width: 190},
   
];

rowData = [
 
    {select: "",ActionCode: 'C-IO', ActionName: 'Begin Golas Workflow', DueDate: "MM/DD/YYYY 12:00 PM"},
    { ActionCode: 'C-IO-A2', ActionName: 'Identify Tobacco triggers', DueDate: "MM/DD/YYYY 12:00 PM" },
    { ActionCode: 'C-MPS', ActionName: 'Set up a Goal', DueDate: "MM/DD/YYYY 12:00 PM" },
    { ActionCode: 'C-PA', ActionName: 'Set up a Goal', DueDate: "MM/DD/YYYY 12:00 PM" },
    { ActionCode: 'C-PA', ActionName: 'Set up a Goal', DueDate: "MM/DD/YYYY 12:00 PM" },
    { ActionCode: 'CODE#', ActionName: 'Set up a Goal', DueDate: "MM/DD/YYYY 12:00 PM" }];
```

I have tried many ways but Iam unable to move the checkbox and the text in cells to right
Can anyone help e on the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align cell content to center, set `cellClass` in column definition:

```js
{ headerName:'Select',width: 80,field:'select',checkboxSelection:true, cellClass: 'cellCenter' }
```

and define the class in CSS as follows:

```css
.cellCenter .ag-cell-wrapper {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Josef Blaha , One more small requirement is  in the above code which I have written it is showing the borders for all cells columns but except the checkbox column can you help me how to add the border

Comment: @user1 I don't understand which border and why it wouldn't show. Please create a new question, include some screenshot, how do you currently add borders etc.

Answer (score 0):

`::ng-deep.ag-cell-wrapper{justify-content: center;}`

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.